# can't figure out how to fix type dependency

Tags: c++

I have this header file:

```
//region.hpp
#ifndef REGION_HPP
#define REGION_HPP 
...
#include "spacepoint.hpp"

class Image;
//class SpacePoint;

class Region
{
    Rectangle<SpacePoint> boundaries;
...
```

it gives this error

```
error: ‘SpacePoint’ was not declared in this scope
```

when I uncomment `class SpacePoint` i get this:

```
In instantiation of ‘class Rectangle<SpacePoint>’:
region.hpp:15:27:   required from here
rectangle.hpp:19:7: error: ‘Rectangle<T>::start’ has incomplete type
```

I tried to reproduce the problem with a smaller test program but I can't.
I don't know how to go about solving this.

Comment: Do spacepoint.hpp try to include region.hpp?

Comment: Is SpacePoint declared in a namespace by chance?

Comment: Where is `Rectangle` defined?

Comment: @Matteo spacepoint.hpp does not include regionpoint.hpp directly; but spacepoint.hpp includes image.hpp; image.hpp includes regionpoint.hpp; and regionpoint.hpp includes region.hpp; is this the problem?

Comment: @Darius there aren't any namespaces

Comment: @Jaywalker `Rectangle` is defined in rectangle.hpp and rectangle.cpp

Comment: @titus: yes, that's probably the problem; region.hpp gets included by spacepoint.hpp before SpacePoint gets defined; when trying to re-include spacepoint.hpp, this is blocked by its header guards, and the net result is that you reach the definition of Region without having SpacePoint defined. Also, you cannot get away with a forward declaration, since the Rectangle template needs to have a full definition for SpacePoint. You have to re-think your dependency chain, and find some point where a forward declaration can suffice to break the cyclic dependence between headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Matteo's guidance I fixed the issue.
With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190597/open-source-tool-to-visualize-c-c-header-file-dependencies) answer I configured doxygen to show the header files dependency.
It was easier to find the loops this way.
Where an include wasn't necessary I removed the include and added a declaration.
In the case of `spacepoint.hpp` I effectively turned `#include <image.hpp>` to `class Image;`

Before:
[image]
After:
(the graph is smaller as `spacepoint.hpp` doesn't depend on `image.hpp` anymore)
[image]

Comment: I like the second graph better.